# Swift dictionary to array of dictionarys

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary of Strings and Bools as simplified here:

```
var dict: [String : Bool] = ["A": true, "B": false, "C": true]
```

Which I would like to convert to an array of dictionaries as below (i.e. both the dict keys and values will become values inside another dictionary, but each will have a new dictionary key of "id" and "enabled":

```
var array = [["id": "A", "enabled": true], ["id": "B", "enabled": false], ["id": "C", "enabled": true]]
```

I haven't been able to find a solution to this. What's the best approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 4.0**

You have to take array of `[String : Any]` dictionary.

```
var dict: [String : Bool] = ["A": true, "B": false, "C": true]

var array: [[String : Any]] = []

for (key,value) in dict {
    array.append(["id" : key, "enabled" : value])
}

print(array) // [["id": "C", "enabled": true], ["id": "B", "enabled": false], ["id": "A", "enabled": true]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `map` on the key/value pairs:

```
 let dict: [String : Bool] = ["A": true, "B": false, "C": true]

 let array = dict.map { key, value in ["id": key, "enabled": value] }

 print(array)
```

Output:

> ```
> [["id": "C", "enabled": true], ["id": "B", "enabled": false], ["id": "A", "enabled": true]]
> ```

The result of `map` is an array.  In this case, it is `[[String : Any]]` - an array of dictionaries of with `String` keys and `Any` values.  Running `map` on a dictionary executes the closure on each key/value pair of the dictionary and returns a value for the resulting array. In this case, we are returning a `[String : Any]` dictionary that we are constructing from the `key` and `value`.

Comment: Many thanks! I think I overcomplicated the issue for myself. I will probably use this solution, but have accepted @Jaydeep's as it's clearer for future visitors.

Comment: You are free to choose whichever solution you think is best. The use of `map` becomes very clear once you get used to using it, and I suggest you do because it comes in handy quite often.